# Problematic bluetooth installation

Tags: windows-8, drivers, bluetooth

When I try to install Qualcomm Atheros Bluetooth (sp60480) I recive error message that: The device may not be present or have been ejected/unplugged from system. Insert or reinsert now.

There seems to be a problem in bluetooth in my laptop because it disappears from time to time and I have to install it. This time I tried to do it by myself (with the set of drivers I got along with the laptop) and this message keeps coming up. I searched for online forums and they seemed to be out of solutions or abandoned. Any help?

Comment: Microsoft's Bluetooth Stack in Windows 8/8.1 is really messed up. I spent about 2 months fiddling with a bluetooth adapter before giving up. I hear that disabling Windows update and installing a different Bluetooth stack can work, but that of course leaves you to having to do updates yourself, which is a pain.

Comment: And your laptop make/model is? ...

Comment: @DavidPostill - hp2000   And now bluetooth is available again. I have no idea how that happened.